# twitter post video using chanked api using php is not working

Tags: php, api, twitter

hear is my code it's showing me error when i am uploading video on twitter

```
<?php
    $video = 'images/video1.mp4'; /// video size is 2 mb and it's time duration around 20 seconeds
    $code = $twitter->upload('media/upload',
                             ["command" => "INIT",
                              "total_bytes" => (int)filesize($video),
                              'media_type' => 'video/mp4']
                            );
    var_dump($code);
    $video_media_id = $code->media_id_string;
    $fp = fopen($video, 'r');
    $segment_id = 0;
    while (! feof($fp)) {
        $chunk = fread($fp, 1048576); // 1MB per chunk for this sample
        $twitter->upload('media/upload',
                         ["command" => "APPEND",
                          "media_id" => $video_media_id,
                          "media_data" => base64_encode($chunk),
                          "segment_index" => $segment_id]
                        );
        $segment_id++;
    }
    $final=$twitter->upload('media/upload',
                            ["command" => "FINALIZE",
                             "media_id" => $video_media_id]
                           );
    var_dump($final);
    $parameters = [
        'status' => 'hear is my video twittsvbn',
        'media_id' => $video_media_id
    ];
    print_r($parameters);
    $tweet=  $twitter->post('statuses/update',  $parameters);
    echo json_encode($tweet); 
    ?>
```

> it was showing me error 
>           object(stdClass)#933 (2) {
>             ["request"]=>
>             string(22) "/1.1/media/upload.json"
>             ["error"]=>
>             string(51) "Segments do not add up to provided total file size."
>           }

Comment: What `Content-Type` header are you setting for the `APPEND` requests? I had the same error till I've set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` value.